# Learning resources for Probability Distributions/Models

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, textbook-recommendation

I've a good background in basic probability. I need to learn and get a good grip on the probability distributions and stochastic processes, counting processes, and other related topics.

I am already familiar with the basics of distributions like Binomial, Poisson, Normal etc.

I have started studying from the [book by Sheldon Ross](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123756863). But honestly, I am finding it as a too-much-details-but-no-examples kind of book. It complicates concepts more than necessary. I am looking for a better book for beginners, if there is any.

Also it would be great if I can learn from any video lectures available online. I find it easier and faster to learn that way. The [MIT OCW lectures](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/index.htm) do not cover all the topics I am looking for.

Please suggest good books/lectures.

Comment: Try 'A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory' by Jeffrey Rosenthal. You'll have to buy the book, but the answers to odd-numbered questions are available on-line.

Comment: On hold! Where should I ask such questions? Which site of StackExchange?

Comment: Try going through avaiable answers + MathStackExchange